# Connecting from .net windows form(stand alone application) to oracle database

Tags: .net, oracle

I am trying to connect from .net windows application to oracle database.
   Do we have to install oracle client in every system where the application
   is running to connect to the remote oracle database..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need to go and grab the [Oracle Data Provider](http://www.oracle.com/technology/tech/windows/odpnet/index.html) which will enable you to query Oracle databases using standard ADO.NET access patterns.

Comment: Oracle Data Provider is 287 mb..is there any other option to 
 access oracle database with less download capacity

Comment: While m_arnell's answer is technically correct, this one is better.  Microsoft is dropping (has dropped) the Oracle System.Data.OracleClient support.  ODP is the current suggested method of accessing Oracle databases.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to "install" it, but you do have to provide the appropriate DLLs with your assembly.

Comment: i am using System.data.oracleclient but it is throwing error
as oracle client required.(oracle database is in other system)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have either the full Oracle database client installed (or the [instant client](http://www.oracle.com/technology/tech/oci/instantclient/index.html)) on each workstation in order to communicate with an Oracle database server.

This is completely separate to the "OracleClient" ADO.net classes.

Answer (score 0):

Check answers to question: [Connection C# to Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626636/connecting-c-to-oracle) for list of possible solutions for interfacing to Oracle.