# VBSCRIPT connection to Oracle failing due to driver

Tags: sql, oracle, vbscript

I am using a vbscript which connects to SQL.
My connection String look like

```
connectionString = "DRIVER={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};SERVER=convcsd;User Id=sysman;Password=csaadmin;"
    Set connection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
```

It is working on one server but not on another. it gives an error :

> The oracle(tm) and networking components were not found. These
>   components are supplied by oracle corporation..
>
> You will be unable to use this driver until these components have been
>   installed.

Please let me know how to add ODBC driver. I researched but not able to get through.

Comment: take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626636/connecting-c-sharp-to-oracle

Comment: you need to install Oracle client.

Comment: MS don't ship any oracle driver. The Oracle ODBC in the list is just a empty cell. You have to install the oracle client as Sathya already said. Then create a connection and use Provider=MSDAORA.1; in your connectionString.

Comment: But it is working on one machine and not working on another. I am confused here.. Isnt SQL+ an oracle client. In case not, please guide what an oracle client is. Thanks for your help

Comment: The Oracle Client is not available on the machine your using now and should be installed like suggested. Check [this](http://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle) source for more on ConnectionString and Oracle.

Comment: Take a look at Oracles Downloads here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/visual-studio/downloads/index.html

Comment: guido gautier Please let me know is SQL Plus an oracle client.. In case yes.. I do have it in my machine which I am running the script on

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL Plus is an Oracle client yes but that is not enough to be able to use your script. You need an ODBC driver and prefable an OleDb driver (is faster) for Oracle on each pc you're going to  use your script.

Compare the ODBC drivers between two 2 pc's with the Microsoft ODBC administrator (type ODBC in your startmenu searchwindow) and you will notice the difference. Use your Oracle installpackage and check the option to install the OleDb driver.

There is a Microsoft and an Oracle version, again it is best to use the Oracle driver. The connection string for Oracle OleDb is

```
Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;User ID=<user name>;Password=<password>;Data Source=<data source>
```